# Remote MySQL Connection in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm beginning to migrate a software project from being a desktop application to a web application. Currently I am using a local PHP/MySQL connection that is associated with the desktop it is installed on.

I'm hoping to untangle this and am trying to create a MySQL database through my 1and1 account. I had no trouble creating a database and recorded my account information. I'd like to be able to edit this database using PHP scripts on my system. However, I haven't been able to get a working connection string going. When I run the following PHP script:

```
$hostname="db*********.db.1and1.com";
$database="db*********";
$username="dbo*********";
$password="*********";

$link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
```

I get the following error when I run the script in my webbrowser:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Unknown MySQL server host 'db*********.db.1and1.com' (11001) in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\Remote_MySQL\rightbid_database_initialize.php on line 74
Connection failed: Unknown MySQL server host 'db*********.db.1and1.com' (11001)
```

How do I get my local system to recognize the 1and1 server host? Am I structuring my connection string correctly? Is it possible to access a remote server from a locally hosted Windows PHP connection?

Thanks!

Comment: is your account on 1and1.com using cPanel?

Answer (score 2):

I assume what's happening if that 1&1 are blocking any connections coming from outside of their network.

Try connecting using

```
mysql -h HOST -u USERNAME -p DATABASENAME
```

Good luck

Comment: yeah, 1&1 only allow access to their DB servers from their own webservers, so remotely connecting from your desktop is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the MySQL server on 1and1 will accept connections from remote clients. Not just on localhost, and also make sure port 3306 is open to the server.

Comment: Bonus: 1and1 has guide you you can enable remote mysql connection. Check https://help.1and1.com/servers-c37684/dedicated-server-linux-c37687/administration-c37694/enable-remote-connections-to-mysql-a781586.html